# How I can know the FuelPHP version?

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have downloaded FuelPHP some time ago but when I'm developing I have trouble with upload error function.

I think that it is an issue with old FuelPHP version. I know new version does not have that issue.

But I don't know where to find the FuelPHP version.

Can you give me a suggestion on how to find the FuelPHP version?

Comment: Look in the source code? It should have a version notice there.

Comment: what is the source code must i look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check inside the file `classes/fuel.php`:

```
const VERSION = '1.3-dev';
```

https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.3/develop/classes/fuel.php#L29

Answer (score 0):

Check with README.md file, it's there: "* Version: 1.2"

Comment: $ grep -ri version fuelphp_dir